# Javascript not working on Azure AD B2C custom signin

Tags: javascript, html, azure

I am trying to get javascript to run on an Azure AD B2C signin page, but it's not working and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I'm using user flows with a custom signin page. To keep it as simple as possible, my custom page HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Login Page</title>
    <script>
    function displayText() {
      var welcomeText = document.getElementById('welcomeText');
        welcomeText.textContent = 'Welcome to the login page!';
    }
    </script> 

</head>
<body onload="displayText()">
    <p id="welcomeText"></p> 
    <div id="api"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is hosted in an Azure Blob Storage Container, and the custom page loads correctly when I test the signin, only the javascript doesn't seem to be working.

When I open the page from blob storage it works as expected:

[image: Loading from blob storage]

However when loading the signin page the welcome text is missing (note the page title is updated to match the HTML):
[image]

Things I have confirmed:

1. Javascript is enabled in my browser
2. Script is in the head tags
3. Javascript is enabled:
   [image]
4. I'm using version 2.1.12 of page layout (and have tried other versions with no luck):
   [image]

What am I missing please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be due to conflicts in div id to read the id by element.

As a workaround, you can create a label and add text to it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
   <script>
        var label = document.createElement('label');
         label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Welcome to the Login page @')); 
         document.body.appendChild(label);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="api"></div>         
</body>
</html>
```

which will show the text on top of the page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler not being run may be caused by the B2C UI overriding them to ensure proper function.

As a workaround, try using the [`DOMContentLoaded` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event), or a [self-executing anonymous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (also known as an Immediately Invoked Function Expression).

```js
(() => {
    var welcomeText = document.getElementById('welcomeText');
    welcomeText.textContent = 'Welcome to the login page!';
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I am new to javascript, so it makes sense if that's where I'm making a mistake.  I tried the self-executing anonymous function in the <head> and it didn't work either on the B2C sign in page or when loaded directly from blob storage. So I moved it to the <body> and it works when loaded from blob storage, but not on the B2C sign in page - where it instead appears as text in the body.  Maybe this can indicate that I've missed something on B2C? Please see screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/EAwBjgs

Comment: I have also tried using an event listener for the DOMContentLoaded event, however had the same results - worked when loaded from blob storage directly, but did not work when used as custom UI for the B2C login page.